# ChromeCast audio firmware 1.24.88047 broken?

Tags: google-cast

I've developped an application that communicates directly (socket level) with CC devices (for audio) but lastest FW release 1.24.88047 broke it. The application load the default receiver and relies on the protocol's requestId (set in JSON payload) to queue requests and pair request/response.

Typically, I do a LAUNCH (default receiver), a LOAD and a PLAY and everytime I wait for a status response that contains the requestId of the previous request before posting the next one.

When the user wants to stop, I send a STOP. At next playback request, I will send a LOAD then a PLAY again. Now what happens with FW 1.24.88047 is that after a STOP has been sent when a track was playing, the next LOAD will never receive a matching response, so the queue is stalled. The CCA does the HTTP request to get the audio data after the LOAD, but that's all (whetver autoplay is set in LOAD or not). Even if I force a PLAY, nothing happen. No MEDIA_STATUS and no playback of course.

I've been able to implement a workaround to stop the default receiver each time the user wants to stop a song, but this is very non elegant and slow. I need to restart the receiver every time. Is this a bug with this FW?

NB: if I wait for the track to end naturally, detect it and send a LOAD for the next track, that still works as usual

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you open a ticket at the Cast SDK issue tracker

Comment: I did here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62038754 - this is now corrected in beta 1.25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug acknowledged by Google Cast team and corrected in FW 1.25+